Get the list of labels
I work with TeXnicCenter and I wanted to know if I could, by typing \ref{ have the list of labels already defined to facilitate the entry?
My document is quite long, so it is quite tedious.
PS: I am with TeXnicCenter but I can change if it is not the right tool (I work under Windows)

No idea about texniccenter, but texstudio offers such functionality: https://texstudio-org.github.io/editing.html#reference-bibid-completion

Use the package refcheck, this will work with any editor. In a MWE.tex like this:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{refcheck}
\begin{document}
\section{foo}\label{foo} this is the unreferenced foo section  
\section{bar}\label{bar} this is the bar section \ref{bar}  
\section{baz}\label{baz} this is the baz section in page \pageref{baz}  
\begin{figure} \caption{a figure}\label{fig} \end{figure}
\end{document}

The MWE.log will show this:
Package refcheck Warning: Unused label `foo' on input line 4.

Package refcheck Warning: Unused label `fig' on input line 7.

And in the MWE.pdf you will see referenced labels as: <label> and unferenced labels as ?<label>?:

Also warn about unlabelled equations and unused bitiems. See the manual for more details.
